# C# errors because of same name or just wrong syntax?

Tags: c#

For an exercise, I have to create a library of sorts. The project specs indicate that there should be a class `Book` and `Borrower` with fields:

```
+---------------------------+            +--------------------------+
|Book                       |            |Borrower                  |
+---------------------------+            +--------------------------+ 
|private string title       |            |private string name       |
|private string author      |            |private Book b            |
|private int ISBN           |
```

and these *methods*:

```
|public Book(string,string,int)|         |public Borrower(String)  |
|public string GetAuthor()     |         |public string GetName()  |
|public string GetTitle()      |         |public Book GetBook()    |
|public int GetISBN()          |         |public void SetBook(Book)|
|// add methods, if needed     |         |                         |
+------------------------------+         +-------------------------+
```

So I code this into my compiler but in my `Borrower` class I have errors like:

```
class Borrower
{
    private string name;
    private Book b;

    public Borrower(string n)
    {
        name = n;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public Book GetBook()
    {
        return b;
    }

    public void SetBook(Book) //I get an error here (Identifier expected)
    {
        Book = b; // error here says Book is type but is used as a variable
    }
}
```

This is my `Book` class there are no errors here

```
class Book
{
    private string title, author;
    private int ISBN;

    public Book(string a, string b, int c)
    {
        title = a;
        author = b;
        ISBN = c;
    }

    public string GetAuthor()
    {
        return author;
    }

    public string GetTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public int GetISBN()
    {
        return ISBN;
    }
}
```

Do I get the errors because I have a *method* `Book` which is the same as the name of the class or can I actually use the class as a *method*?

Comment: you must include an identifier like so: `public void SetBook(Book b)` also change this `Book = b;` to this `this.b = b;`

Comment: Aside from revising how to write method parameters, now would be a good time to learn about *actual* C# properties - your code doesn't have *any* properties at the moment, just methods and fields.

Comment: welp all this time I've been saying property

Comment: Read up on [constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors), too, which will let you know what "a *method* `Book` which is the same name as the name of the class" is for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method

```
public void SetBook(Book)
{
    Book = b;
}
```

should be rewritten as follows:

```
public void SetBook(Book b)
{
    this.b = b;
}
```

Otherwise the object passed as parameter would have no name. I used the same name as your field `Book b`, so I added `this.b` for disambiguation.